# How do I find the oldest used files from a program that links its bins, like Homebrew?

Tags: bash, perl, homebrew

How do I find the oldest used files from this?

```
MBP:~ user$ \ls -la /usr/local/bin/ | egrep -i "Cellar|Cask" | head
lrwxr-xr-x    1 user  admin       37 Sep 13 12:19 2to3 -> ../Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.5/bin/2to3
lrwxr-xr-x    1 user  admin       43 Sep 13 12:26 2to3-3.10 -> ../Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.13/bin/2to3-3.10
lrwxr-xr-x    1 user  admin       42 Sep 13 12:19 2to3-3.11 -> ../Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.5/bin/2to3-3.11
lrwxr-xr-x    1 user  admin       40 Sep 13 12:35 2to3-3.9 -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.18/bin/2to3-3.9
lrwxr-xr-x    1 user  admin       37 Aug 26 14:25 4channels -> ../Cellar/libraw/0.21.1/bin/4channels
lrwxr-xr-x    1 user  admin       52 Sep 13 12:34 Magick++-config -> ../Cellar/imagemagick/7.1.1-15_1/bin/Magick++-config
lrwxr-xr-x    1 user  admin       54 Sep 13 12:34 MagickCore-config -> ../Cellar/imagemagick/7.1.1-15_1/bin/MagickCore-config
lrwxr-xr-x    1 user  admin       54 Sep 13 12:34 MagickWand-config -> ../Cellar/imagemagick/7.1.1-15_1/bin/MagickWand-config
lrwxr-xr-x    1 user  admin       36 Jun  4  2023 acountry -> ../Cellar/c-ares/1.19.1/bin/acountry
lrwxr-xr-x    1 user  admin       32 Jun  4  2023 adig -> ../Cellar/c-ares/1.19.1/bin/adig
MBP:~ user$
```

If anyone uses Homebrew on Mac, I'm looking to see if I can or should clean up anything.  I have a ton of installed apps, and a `brew update` takes forever.  I need to find which apps I stopped using.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions. You might ask how to do this in _one_ language but then we'd require you to exhibit some effort before asking. In the meantime, please don't spam tags indiscriminately.

Comment: @tripleee : Well, sorry for what appears to be spam.  I did expend effort.  But what I think I have is an answer to my question, so I posted it like that.  I'm curious if others have a better way, and I'd be looking for bash/perl/python solutions, which is why I tagged those.  LMK if you think I should merge the answer I posted into the question, or if there's a better board I should be posting to.  I now see superuser seems to have more homebrew stuff, should I be there & not post here?

Comment: No, your question should remain strictly a question; but this has nothing with Python to do as currently asked. I have simply removed that tag. It would not be hard to translate your script to Python but that's not an acceptable question here (without a significantly more focused question, such as "how can I translate [a single Perl idiom] to Python".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Links in the input directory sorted by the oldest-used, per resolved symlinks <sup>†</sup>

```
use File::Spec;

my $dir = '/usr/local/bin';

my @sorted_by_oldest_used = 
    map { $_->[0] }
    sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] }
    map { 
        my $t = readlink;
        $t = "$dir/$t" if not File::Spec->file_name_is_absolute($t); 
        $t =~ /Cellar|Cask/ ? [ $_, -A $t ] : ()
    }   
    grep { -l }     # keep only links
    glob "$dir/*";
```

It tests whether the target name is absolute because `readlink` may return the name with only the path relative to the symlink directory, or the full path.

Please let me know if I need to explain this code.

The `glob` pulls everything that is matched by the wildcard-ed expression.  If you need to be more precise about the entries add to that `grep` filter and see [filetest (-X)](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X) for different flags.

Include this code in your programs as suitable.  For a demo, here is a command-line version

```
perl -MFile::Spec -wE'
    $d = shift // q(/usr/local/bin); 
    say for
        map { $_->[0] }
        sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] }
        map {
            my $t = readlink;
            $t = "$d/$t" if not File::Spec->file_name_is_absolute($t);
            $t =~ /Cellar|Cask/ ? [ $_, -A $t ] : ()
        }
        grep { -l }
        glob "$d/*"'
```

This can be copy-pasted into a terminal and ran, in most shells.

Or, if there is no need for the path test this simplifies a little.  Then let's also keep more info<sup>†</sup>

```
perl -MData::Dumper -wE'
    $d = shift // q(/usr/local/bin); 
    say Dumper
        sort { $b->[2] <=> $a->[2] }
        map { (-l and ($t = readlink) =~ /Cellar|Cask/) ? [ $_, $t, -A $t ] : () }
        glob "$d/*"'
```

This uses `/usr/local/bin` by default, unless a directory is given on the command line at invocation, as `perl -wE'...' dirname`.

I don't use Homebrew on a Mac so let me know if something's off in relation to that.  Thanks to `tripleee` for comments.

---

<sup>†</sup>  Or, keep more information from processing for a more sensible analysis

```
use File::Spec;

use Data::Dumper;

my @sorted_by_oldest_used = 
    sort { $b->[2] <=> $a->[2] }
    map { 
        my $t = readlink;
        $t = "$dir/$t" if not File::Spec->file_name_is_absolute($t); 
        $t =~ /Cellar|Cask/ ? [ $_, $t, -A $t ] : ()
    }   
    grep { -l }
    glob "$dir/*";

say Dumper @sorted_by_oldest_used;
```

The final array, that is then printed, now has arrayrefs for elements, each with link name, target name, and the *number of days* since last access (`-A`).

I use Data::Dumper to print a complex data structure because it comes in core but there are other libraries for that, like `Data::Dump`, `Data::Printer`, and more.

Comment: The `glob` needs to go after the `map` to check if the symlink is to somewhere in Cask or Cellar. I guess the `map { -l ? readlink : $_ }` could be changed into `map { readlink } grep { -l }`

Comment: Something like this? `perl -wE 'say for map { $_->[1] } sort { $b->[0] <=> $a->[0] } map { [ -A, $_ ] } grep { /(Cellar|Cask)/ } map { readlink } grep { -l } @ARGV' /usr/local/bin/*` ... though this seems to put the newest first, not the oldest.

Comment: @tripleee  Thanks for fixes!  And for comments ... but I don't know what the problem is -- it works in my tests.  For one, I want both links and non-links as they want to check all apps I assume.  I can't test on a Mac though :(

Comment: Homebrew installs links in `/usr/local/bin` and the OP wants to find those symlinks which have been the most recently used. Binaries which are not symlinks are not of interest for this particular use case, and obviously the file names of those files will basically never contain `Cask` or `Cellar` anyway.

Comment: @tripleee "_this seems to put the newest first_"  -- that command should put oldest first (largest `-A`, days since last access)

Comment: Yeah, I gave up on figuring what exactly was wrong. When I attempted to include `$_->[0]` in the output I got a lot of `undef` warnings so probably related to that; but when I stripped it down to just the `-A` result it was working fine ... so probably something is still off in my logic.

Comment: @tripleee "_Homebrew installs links in `/usr/local/bin`_" -- ah, so this _is_ a bit about Homebrew.  Thank you, will edit now to filter out non-links.  (I have no idea what `Cask` and `Cellar` mean.)

Comment: I guess the problem with my earlier attempt is that these symlink destinations don't have access times. Here is a version which checks the access time of the symlink. `perl -wE 'say for map { $_->[1] } sort { $b->[0] <=> $a->[0] }  grep { $_->[1] =~ /(Cellar|Cask)/ } map { [ $_->[0], readlink $_->[1] ] } grep { -l $_->[1] } map { [ -A, $_ ] } @ARGV' /usr/local/bin/*`

Comment: ... Though this prints the symlink _destination_ where probably you would like the final `say` to print the _source._

Comment: So finally `perl -wE 'say for map { $_->[1] } sort { $b->[0] <=> $a->[0] }  grep { $_->[2] =~ /(Cellar|Cask)/ } map { [ $_->[0], $_->[1], readlink $_->[1] ] } grep { -l $_->[1] } map { [ -A, $_ ] } @ARGV' /usr/local/bin/*`

Comment: @tripleee  "_symlink destinations don't have access times_"  -- that's a substantial question -- are access times on a symlink or on its source?  I'd always guess the source, but that may be wrong.  On my linux system I get  the same value (with `-A`) for both.

Comment: @tripleee  At any rate, I'd wait for the OP to see what they say with their Mac.  What I posted works for me (Archlinux here and I tested on a distro which uses Redhat binaries as well), and you've posted working versions for when symlinks sources don't have `-A` (which is weird, isn't it?) -- thank you.

Comment: @tripleee  Btw, I changed code in the answer to keep only links, thanks for that clarification.  (just `map { -l ? readlink : () }` -- with `()` it acts as a filter as well as it returns an empty list)

Comment: @tripleee  Again, thanks for comments -- I think I figured out what may have been the problem with that `-A` -- the `readlink` may return the name without the path!  (If the target is in the same directory as the link, and probably depending on what the system does.) Then `-A` chokes on that of course since there is no such file.  (Otherwise how could `-A` not work?)  I rewrote to add a version that handles that.

Comment: Ah, brilliant! Your File::Spec version doesn't print anything for me, though; there are still no matches for `glob "$d/*{Cellar|Cask}*"` in my `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: @tripleee  Um ... you mean files with `Cellar` or `Cask` in your `/usr/local/bin` are NOT found by `glob "$d/*{Cellar|Cask}*"` ...? (with `$d=q(/usr/local/bin)`) ... I must be going crazy ...

Comment: @tripleee  Ahhhhh!  It's `*{Cellar,Cask}*`, NOT NOT NOT `Cellar|Cask`.  Not a regex, but shell-style globbing.  grrrrr....

Comment: Still no matches on that; we want files for which _the result of `readlink`_ matches `Cellar` or `Cask`, not files whose names match that pattern.

Comment: In the meantime, `perl -MFile::Basename -wE 'say for map { $_->[1] } sort { $b->[0] <=> $a->[0] } map { [ -A, $_ ] } grep { /Cellar|Cask/ } map { dirname($_) . "/" . readlink($_) } grep { -l } @ARGV' /usr/local/bin/*` avoids the undef, as predicted by your earlier comment, but still prints the symlink destination, not the source.

Comment: Their shell command line greps on Cellar or Cask in names in /usr/local/bin (link names), not target ...?

Comment: No, the `ls -la` includes the result of resolving the symlink, which is what they `grep` on, as you can also see in the actual results. For example, `/usr/local/bin/2to3` is a match because its symlink points to `../Cellar/...`

Comment: I see. (They merely grep out of the whole output of ls -l, of course)  Turns out I was really sloppy on this, it's right there I see now (just as you say).  Ugh.  Thank you very much for all this talk ... will now read that carefully and fix

Comment: @tripleee So they need to clean up from Homebrew, the lnks themselves in /usr/local/bin (so that need be printed), not the targets?  But the targets do have  a correct `-A` on a Mac as well?

Comment: Yeah, the problem was fixed by adding the `dirname` of the original before attempting `-A`

Comment: Right, but I need to print link names, not targets, and need to filter on Cellar|Cask in target names ... ugh.  I didn't look at their output because I thought it didn't matter (as I misunderstood it), that it's Mac details :(  Very annoying

Comment: Yeah, my fixed version ended up a lot less elegant than your original. I'm hoping you can use my input to come up with a similarly slick final answer. I'm definitely hoping to be able to upvote this once it's working.

Comment: @tripleee  Fixed, hopefully.  [This isn't about points, just want to leave good posts around, if at all possible]  But it's no slick affair, as one has to filter on the target name (so need `readlink` upfront) but even earlier need to filter out non-links (don't want a syscall if it isn't a link at all) _and_ have to test whether filename is absolute ... and need the link name itself in the end!  It's twisted then folded, four times over.  Anyway, what a roller-coaster :( ... a reminder to _always_ read questions carefully.  (Another reminder I mean)  Thank you!

Comment: @tripleee As for your final version, note that `readlink` may well return the fqn -- and I think in their case it does -- so one _has to_ test before prepending directory name.  I think that `readlink` returns name w/o path only when it's in the same directory.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. The command-line version now works for me. (The "more information" one returns `undef` because it can't get the access time of the symlink destination, but it's now clear how to fix that. I suppose the OP might prefer the access time of the source rather than the destination; sorry for muddying the waters around that.)

Comment: @tripleee  Thank you, I'll look more tomorrow.  Way past bed time here...  Btw, from my previous comment, "_...`readlink` returns name w/o path only when it's in the same directory..._"  -- it may return a path relative to where the link is or it may return the full path.  Will clean up that statement

Answer (score 0):

A Perl script to get bash Access times of the target of the links placed in /usr/local/bin.  Then it shows the oldest-accessed files last.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Looking for old homebrew apps to get rid of

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::stat;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

# Extra line for readability after previous PS1 prompt
print "\n";

# Find files and generate access times
open( my $fh, '-|', 'find /usr/local/bin -type l -exec sh -c "readlink -f {}" \; | grep -E "Cellar|Cask"' )
  or die "Failed to execute find command: $!";

my %data_res;
my $count = 0;

while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my $target_file    = $_;
    my $file_stat      = stat($target_file) or die "Failed to get stats for $target_file: $!";
    my $formatted_date = strftime( "%Y_%b_%d_%H:%M:%S", localtime( $file_stat->atime ) );

    # Add filename to the date's collection of files
    $data_res{$formatted_date}{$target_file} = 1;

    $count++;
}

# Oldest last since that's what's viewable when script is done,
# and user is looking for the oldest-touched files (apps).
my @sorted_dates = sort { $b cmp $a } keys %data_res;

# Print 'formatted_date<TAB>/file/path'
foreach my $date (@sorted_dates) {
    foreach my $file ( keys %{ $data_res{$date} } ) {
        printf "%s\t%s\n", $date, $file;
    }
}

# Extra line for readability before next PS1 prompt
print "\n";
```

Shows the oldest used homebrew bin paths last:

```
MBP:~ user$ homebrew-get-dates.pl | tail
2022_Sep_17_16:55:25    /usr/local/Cellar/gdbm/1.23/bin/gdbm_load
2022_Sep_17_16:55:25    /usr/local/Cellar/gdbm/1.23/bin/gdbmtool
2022_Sep_17_16:55:25    /usr/local/Cellar/gdbm/1.23/bin/gdbm_dump
2022_Sep_17_16:55:16    /usr/local/Cellar/jemalloc/5.3.0/bin/jeprof
2022_Sep_17_16:55:16    /usr/local/Cellar/jemalloc/5.3.0/bin/jemalloc-config
2022_Sep_17_16:55:16    /usr/local/Cellar/jemalloc/5.3.0/bin/jemalloc.sh
2022_Sep_17_16:54:43    /usr/local/Cellar/lz4/1.9.4/bin/lz4
2021_Oct_17_20:47:13    /usr/local/Caskroom/vlc/3.0.16/vlc.wrapper.sh
2021_Oct_02_20:18:25    /usr/local/Cellar/npth/1.6/bin/npth-config

MBP:~ user$
```

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor); and avoid the [useless `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat). Probably better to fold the **stat()** call into the Perl script, too.

Comment: It would be better to do all of this in a single script which could be either Perl or Python.

Comment: Update: I added the bash lines into the perl script as @Malcolm suggested.  This makes the total time to get the answer lower.  But, the downside is that having separate bash lines allows for debugging of the process.  Running this script now takes 19s, and most of that is in the find command.  Debugging it would be better done by caching the find results, which I'm not willing to invest in, since I'm not convinced writing a script to do this is the best way.

Comment: Oooh, I just figured out the for loop comment was about the bash.  @tripleee Why shouldn't one read files inside a bash for loop?

Comment: The colored text is a clickable link which takes you to an explanation. It doesn't mean "don't read lines inside the loop", it means "don't use `for line in $(cat file)`" or etc.

Comment: @triplee That is so cool!  I'm thinking how many times have I done cat inside a for & proly just got lucky, it's so dangerous!  Thank you very much & sorry I didn't see the link!

Comment: Two comments.  First you can run a perl script with the `-d` option to run it in the Perl debugger, or you can just put in print statements for debugging.  Second, I would use the File::Find module and not invoke a separate find command.  Similarly you can read the link and do your pattern matching all in Perl.